# HTML5 Video - Go Fullscreen Automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

Similar issue found [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766164/automatic-fullscreen-html5-video-playback)

My little girl will watch cartoons on my Linux Mint PC running Chrome. I have a BASH pre-compiler that creates all the pages with `video` and `source` tags already baked into the markup. On video end, a 5-second timer (with javascript) pops up, counts down, then redirects to random other pages, that automatically plays the video once the metadata is loaded (all with eventListener's)

I need a way to automatically fullscreen the video. I know that there are ways to do this and that the browser is explicitly disallowing this fullscreen event, as it wasn't user triggered.

I have the following code:

```
video=document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(e){
  if (this.requestFullscreen)
    this.requestFullscreen();
  else if (this.msRequestFullscreen)
    this.msRequestFullscreen();
  else if (this.mozRequestFullScreen) // Note the capital "S" in Screen
    this.mozRequestFullScreen();
  else if (this.webkitRequestFullscreen)
    this.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  video.play();
  video.focus();
}, false)

... insert working-as-intended 'ended' eventListener ...
```

This function works (Almost) as expected. I click the first link, the video loads, goes fullscreen, begins playing, and focuses the video (in case of the user pressing the spacebar, or using arrow keys, etc)

However, the video ends, the timer counts down, page redirects to the next in the queue, but this time, the video does not fullscreen. I am almost positive this is the browser disallowing "unsafe" or "insecure" ... or perhaps simply "annoying" scripts, but in this case, I want a way to allow this functionality anyways. The video should fullscreen on this event regardless of the generally accepted "no don't do that" comments, please.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it happens only with google-chrome, or with others browsers?

Comment: You could try to run Chrome in Kiosk Mode: https://superuser.com/a/716843. Then Chrome would constantly be full-screen.

Comment: As far as I can recall, fullscreen must be initiated by user interaction (ie click)

Comment: I specifically use Google Chrome, however, Firefox and Edge both prove to have the same behaviour regarding triggering fullscreen without user interaction

Answer (score 0):

What you could increment on your code it's to check if your fullscreen it's activated :

```
function IsFullScreenCurrently() {
var full_screen_element = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement || null;

// If no element is in full-screen
if(full_screen_element === null)
    return false;
else
    return true; }
```

you can also use `document.fullscreenEnabled`([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled)) to check if you can engage the full screen on the browser you're using.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm not sure it is inline with what I am attempting to accomplish. This appears to check whether the document can do or is already in fullscreen, correct? How would I implement this to trigger fullscreen automatically (i.e., without user pressing any buttons?)